# Is there a way to re-enable Page Up/Down Keys with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a software that is written in Rails and the Page Up and Down keys are disabled by Javascript (that´s what I was told). Is there a general way to reenable them? I´m sorry if I can´t provide more informations. I´m a total noob with basic HTML and CSS knowledge.

Thank you very much in Advance!

Comment: There's no general way to enable them, as they are by default. You need to find the code that is disabling them and remove it.

Comment: yes, try to use jquery, is simple for this propose.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón are you reviving [old memes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/269001) ?

Comment: @Kaiido i didt know nothing about it( jquery mme),  but as i've read i've got to get you got reason,  jajajjaja

Comment: Thank you guys. @ÁlvaroTouzón I thought you were serious lol. cheers

Comment: Your solution will be to find the script which disabled them, because there are many ways to disable them and it will be hard to guess and implement an enable function for something you don't know how it was disabled.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy  Thank you for the feedback. Much appreciated